# How to work with std_msgs::Int16MultiArray message type?

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, ubuntu, std-msgs, ubuntu-trusty

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What is needed to publish a How to work with std_msgs::Int16MultiArray message?

I tried

```
std_msgs::Int16MultiArray msg;
int16_t *velocities;
msg.data = velocities;
```

but just those few lines gives me errors while compiling

```
error: no match for ‘operator=’ (operand types are ‘std_msgs::Int16MultiArray_<std::allocator<void> >::_data_type {aka std::vector<short int, std::allocator<short int> >}’ and ‘int16_t* {aka short int*}’)
         msg.data = velocities;
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/314002/how-to-work-with-std_msgs::int16multiarray-message-type?/) by [kump](https://answers.ros.org/users/37695/kump/) on ROS Answers with karma: 308 on 2019-01-28

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-01-28**:
I believe this is a duplicate of #q37185.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This works:

```
# definition in header
std::vector<physics::JointPtr> joints;
ros::Publisher rosPub;
std::unique_ptr<ros::NodeHandle> rosNode;

# initialization
this->rosNode.reset(new ros::NodeHandle( node_name ));
this->rosPub = this->rosNode->advertise<std_msgs::Float32MultiArray>("/velocity",1);

# callback function
std_msgs::Float32MultiArray msg;
msg.data.push_back( this->joints[0]->GetVelocity(0) );
msg.data.push_back( this->joints[1]->GetVelocity(0) );
msg.data.push_back( this->joints[2]->GetVelocity(0) );

this->rosPub.publish(msg);
```

---

Originally posted by [kump](https://answers.ros.org/users/37695/kump/) with karma: 308 on 2019-01-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-01-29**:
Please note that you're not initialising the `layout` field here. Subscribers that expect that field to describe the size, dimensionality and shape of the data you're publishing will not work correctly.